# EF Core 7, add support for common table expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to add very simple, basic support for CTEs in EF Core 7, this what I did.

**Step 1**: create `IQueryable` method extensions

```
namespace CTE.Extensions;

public static class CteQueryableExtensions
{
    internal static readonly MethodInfo asCteMethod = typeof(CteQueryableExtensions).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(AsCte) && m.IsGenericMethod);
    internal static readonly MethodInfo thenAsMethod = typeof(CteQueryableExtensions).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(ThenAs) && m.IsGenericMethod);

    public static IQueryable<T> AsCte<T>(this IQueryable<T> definition)
    {
        var methodInfo = asCteMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        var expression = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, definition.Expression);
        return definition.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    public static IQueryable<R> ThenAs<T, R>(
        this IQueryable<T> source, 
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<R>>> definition)
    {
        var methodInfo = thenAsMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(R));
        var expression = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, source.Expression, definition);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<R>(expression);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: this is where am lost, I thought I would find somewhere, where I would simply override a `VisitMethodCall` method and do some simple processing of custom derived LINQ/SQL expressions and get it working.

So my question is how can I get EF Core to translate these extension methods into SQL.

This what I tried:

**Step 1** create `IQueryable` method extensions

```
namespace CTE.Extensions;

public static class CteQueryableExtensions
{
    internal static readonly MethodInfo asCteMethod = typeof(CteQueryableExtensions).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(AsCte) && m.IsGenericMethod);
    internal static readonly MethodInfo thenAsMethod = typeof(CteQueryableExtensions).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(ThenAs) && m.IsGenericMethod);

    public static IQueryable<T> AsCte<T>(this IQueryable<T> definition)
    {
        var methodInfo = asCteMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        var expression = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, definition.Expression);
        return definition.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    public static IQueryable<R> ThenAs<T, R>(
        this IQueryable<T> source, 
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<R>>> definition)
    {
        var methodInfo = thenAsMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(R));
        var expression = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, source.Expression, definition);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<R>(expression);
    }
}
```

**Step 2** declare custom SQL expressions

```
namespace CTE.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Expressions;

public class CteSqlDefinitionExpression : SqlExpression
{
    public SqlExpression Definition { get; }
    public CteSqlDefinitionExpression? Parent { get; private set; }
    public CteSqlDefinitionExpression? Root
    {
        get
        {
            var root = Parent;
            while (root?.Parent != null)
            {
                root = root.Parent;
            }
            return root;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanReduce => false;

    public CteSqlDefinitionExpression(SqlExpression definition, RelationalTypeMapping? typeMapping, CteSqlDefinitionExpression? parent = null)
         : base(definition.Type, typeMapping)
    {
        Definition = definition;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public CteSqlExpression ToCteExpression()
    {
        List<CteSqlDefinitionExpression> definitions = new();
        var parent = this;

        while (parent != null)
        {
            definitions.Add(parent);
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }

        definitions.Reverse();
        return new CteSqlExpression(definitions, TypeMapping);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitChildren(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        var visitedParent = Parent == null ? null : (CteSqlDefinitionExpression)visitor.Visit(Parent);
        var visitedDefinition = (SqlExpression)visitor.Visit(Definition);
        if (ReferenceEquals(Parent, visitedParent) && ReferenceEquals(Definition, visitedDefinition))
            return this;
        return new CteSqlDefinitionExpression(visitedDefinition, TypeMapping, Parent);
    }

    protected override void Print(ExpressionPrinter expressionPrinter)
    {
        //expressionPrinter.Visit(Alias);
        expressionPrinter.Append("\n AS \n(");
        expressionPrinter.Visit(Definition);
        expressionPrinter.Append(")");
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        => base.Equals(obj) && obj is CteSqlDefinitionExpression node && Equals(node);

    private bool Equals([NotNull] CteSqlDefinitionExpression node)
        => Equals(Parent, node.Parent) == true && Definition.Equals(node.Definition);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = new HashCode();
        hash.Add(base.GetHashCode());
        hash.Add(Parent == null ? 0 : Parent.GetHashCode());
        hash.Add(Definition.GetHashCode());
        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }
}

public class CteSqlExpression : SqlExpression
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<CteSqlDefinitionExpression> Definitions { get; } = new List<CteSqlDefinitionExpression>();

    public override bool CanReduce => false;

    public CteSqlExpression(CteSqlDefinitionExpression definition, RelationalTypeMapping? typeMapping)
        : this(new[] { definition }, typeMapping)
    {
    }

    public CteSqlExpression(IEnumerable<CteSqlDefinitionExpression> definitions, RelationalTypeMapping? typeMapping)
        : base(definitions.Last().Type, typeMapping)
    {
        ((List<CteSqlDefinitionExpression>)Definitions).AddRange(definitions.ToArray());
    }

    public CteSqlExpression AddDefinitions(params CteSqlDefinitionExpression[] definitions)
        => new(Definitions.Concat(definitions), TypeMapping);

    protected override Expression VisitChildren(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        var visitedNodes = new List<CteSqlDefinitionExpression>();
        var hasChanges = false;

        foreach (var node in Definitions)
        {
            var visitedNode = (CteSqlDefinitionExpression)visitor.Visit(node);
            visitedNodes.Add(visitedNode);
            hasChanges |= !ReferenceEquals(visitedNode, node);
        }
        return hasChanges ? new CteSqlExpression(visitedNodes, TypeMapping) : this;
    }

    protected override void Print(ExpressionPrinter expressionPrinter)
    {
        expressionPrinter.Visit(new SqlFragmentExpression("WITH "));
        expressionPrinter.VisitCollection(Definitions);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        => base.Equals(obj) && obj is CteSqlExpression node && Equals(node);

    private bool Equals([NotNull] CteSqlExpression node)
        => Definitions.SequenceEqual(node.Definitions);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = new HashCode();
        hash.Add(base.GetHashCode());

        foreach (var node in Definitions)
        {
            hash.Add(node);
        }

        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [linq2db CTE](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html)

Comment: It doesn't support TPT, many-to-many relationships, and it's not working well with [projectable's](https://github.com/koenbeuk/EntityFrameworkCore.Projectables) library